# QwtPlot how to select point(s) curve

Tags: qt, plot, qwt

I have a QwtPlot that contains some curves and I would like to be able to get the selected point(s) (and curve pointer) from these curves : select a point by clicking and select points by dragging a rect.

I use the following code:

```
// Picker with click point machine to provide point selection
QwtPlotPicker* clickPicker = new QwtPlotPicker(this->canvas());
clickPicker->setStateMachine(new QwtPickerClickPointMachine);
clickPicker->setMousePattern(0,Qt::LeftButton,Qt::SHIFT);
connect(clickPicker, SIGNAL(appended(QPointF)),
        this, SLOT(pointSelected(QPointF)));

// Picker with drag rect machine to provide multiple points selection
QwtPlotPicker* rectPicker = new QwtPlotPicker(
            this->xBottom, this->yLeft, QwtPicker::RectRubberBand,
            QwtPicker::AlwaysOff, this->canvas());
QwtPickerDragRectMachine* test = new QwtPickerDragRectMachine();
test->setState(QwtPickerMachine::RectSelection);
rectPicker->setStateMachine(test);
connect(rectPicker, SIGNAL(selected(QRectF)),
        this, SLOT(pointsSelected(QRectF)));
```

but the pointSelected slot is called every time I click on the QwtPlot and not only on a curve

BTW, I also try to connect a slot to the signal [QwtPlotPicker::selected(const QVector &pa)](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_picker.html#a7eb9fdda3166c452660130ceffd1d092) but it is never emitting ...

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more convenient to use the `CanvasPicker` as it comes with the examples and can be extended easily.

Please have a look at the `event_filter` which comes with Qwt. You should use the class `CanvasPicker` (it is not part of the Qwt API, but you'll find the code in the examples).
You can instantiate it in your class using

```
    picker = new CanvasPicker(plot); // plot is a pointer to your instance of QwtPlot
```

You'll see that the event filter is installed in the constructor of `CanvasPicker`.

Now have a look at CanvasPicker::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *e) which is called when an event occurs in the event loop of `QwtPlot`. Implement your application logic in the switch construct, f.i. change `case QEvent::MouseMove:`.